# WMI filter working for some Windows 7 machines but not for others

Tags: windows, group-policy, wmi

I'm trying to use this WMI filter for our Windows 7 64bit machines:

select * from Win32_OperatingSystem where (Caption like "Microsoft Windows 7%") or (Version like "6.1%" and ProductType = "1" and OSArchitecture = "64 ビット") or (OSArchitecture like "64%" and ProductType = "1")

The reason there are three clauses is that we have machines in United States, Japan, and France.  The first clause works for the United States, the second clause works for Japan, and the third clause SHOULD work for France, but doesn't.

I've run the query manually on the French machine using WMITest.exe (http://www.paessler.com/tools/wmitester) and it works.  However, when I run a gpresult /r it shows that the GPO is denied due to the WMI filter.

Why is this happening for French computers only?

Comment: What does the `OSArchitecture` show as on a 64bit machine from France?

Comment: It shows 64-bit

Comment: @Matt Possibly "le 64-bit" ?